# Article before a dependent clause

Tags: grammar, articles, syntactic-analysis

When one writes a noun after a dependent clause, should that noun be preceded by an "a" or an "an".
"That was an, to be quite clear, extremely clever idea."
Or: "That was a, to be quite clear, extremely clever idea."

Comment: Most people would probably stick to the KISS principle here. The next word *(**to**)* starts with a consonant, so just say ***a***. But it's a "pathological" example, so there's no real point in appealing to syntax rules as such. You just have to try and make the best of a bad job. Or move *to be clear* to a more sensible position, since it's inherently clumsy where it is, however you transcribe it (I certainly wouldn't *say* it if I was paying attention to my speech).

Comment: "That was, to be quite clear, an extremely clever idea."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct rule for placement of a pair of parenthetical commas in a sentence](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/420286/correct-rule-for-placement-of-a-pair-of-parenthetical-commas-in-a-sentence). The incorrect example 'the, by its email, CSI has informed us that...' is given.

Comment: Even more relevant than Edwin Ashworth's link may be the question and answers at ["A/An" preceding a parenthetical statement](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3368/a-an-preceding-a-parenthetical-statement). In fact, it looks as though the answers there are entirely on point, despite their being formally about how to handle a situation where a parenthetical phrase comes between an indefinite article and its associated noun.

Answer (score 4):

No native speaker would put the article before the dependent clause in this case. In the example you give the dependent clause modifies the verb (was) and not the noun. The article should go close to the noun and after the dependent clause.

> That was, to be quite clear, an extremely clever idea.

There might be rare cases where the dependent clause really does modify the noun:

> The hunter's video shows a soon to be killed animal.

However this construction is clumsy and hard to understand. Most writers would use hyphens within the dependent clause.

> The hunter's video shows a soon-to-be-killed animal.

In any case usual rules would be followed for deciding between *a* and *an*, which is that the next word controls which one to use

> an animal
>
> a large animal
>
> a soon-to-be-killed animal

Comment: I don't think I would go quite so far as to say "NO native speaker would...", but I take your point.

Comment: Which is the dependent clause here?  Where does 'a' or 'an' precede? I don't think 'a' or 'an'  with a comma immediately following can be called preceding. The type of examples are new to me, and personally, I won't follow it.

Comment: The dependent clause is "to be quite clear".

Comment: I don't think many people would call that a "dependent clause". It is parenthetical.